# Page jumps down when tab is clicked once active

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

So on the site [STVPlus](http://stvplus.com) we use bootstrap and the tabs script to show episodes and articles lists for various tv shows. I am having an issue where once the page has loaded (usually) it works fine, you can select a tab and the appropriate div will show. However if you select an already active div the page jumps down.Also when loading the page with a hash tag like so [episodes hash tag link](http://stvplus.com/#episodes), then it automatically jumps down when page is fully loaded. I have tried stepping through the JS code using chrome dev tools, however I could not find anything obvious.

Any help would be appreciated.

Sample code:

```
$(function()
{
    $('.sidebar').jScrollPane();

  // Bind an event to window.onhashchange that, when the hash changes, gets the
  // hash and adds the class "selected" to any matching nav link.
  $(window).hashchange( function(){
    var hash = location.hash;


    if ( hash == '#episodes'){
        //e.preventDefault();
        $('.nav-pills a:last').tab('show');
    }else{
        //e.preventDefault();
        $('.nav-pills a:first').tab('show');
    }

  })

  // Since the event is only triggered when the hash changes, we need to trigger
  // the event now, to handle the hash the page may have loaded with.
  $(window).hashchange();
  return false;
});
```

the episodes div container is like so

```
<div class="tab-pane" id="episodes">    ..... </div>
```

and the tab you click is like so

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills pull-right" data-tabs="tabs">
   <li class="active"><a href="<?php echo current_url(); ?>#articles">Latest Articles</a></li>
   <li><a href="<?php echo current_url(); ?>#episodes">Upcoming Episodes</a></li>
   </ul>
```

I use the latest jquery, with http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-hashchange-plugin/

Comment: You should post a minimalistic version of the code you are using. Why don't you use the proper initialization instead of binding on the hashtag ? That way you could intercept the clicks. Page jumps are a feature of HTML, either choose directness (IDs in hash) or put your own hashtag <-> tab matcher.

Comment: Thanks I have added sample code. If its a feature, then jquery would be able to prevent that right? I have tried preventdefault in places, no luck yet. How would I go about doing it so it prevents the page jump?

Comment: I don't think you can prevent that. As far as I know it's a browser thing, maybe too low for JS. Do you need to listen on the `hashchange` for something other than the tab pills ?

Comment: Nope its just the tab pills for now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is what would be my approach concerning your problem :

I'm not sure that you need the hashchange plugin - except for some `document.location.hash` fallback (if there's any).

The following code uses the classic bootstrap tabs, manually activated, and a bit of `onready` code that will show the tab matching the hash.

```js
var hasHash = false;
var hash = document.location.hash;
if(hash) {
    hasHash = true;
    var $toggleTab = $('a[href='+hash+']');
    if($toggleTab.length) $toggleTab.tab('show');
}
```

Tab activation :

```
$('.nav > li > a').click(function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.tab('show');
    if(hasHash) document.location.hash = $this.attr('href');
});
```

Based on the HTML :

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills" data-tabs="tabs">
    <li class="active"><a href="#articles" data-target="#articles-tab">Latest Articles</a></li>
    <li><a href="#episodes" data-target="#episodes-tab">Upcoming Episodes</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane" id="episodes-tab">episodes</div>
    <div class="tab-pane active" id="articles-tab">articles</div>
</div>
```

[Demo (jsfiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/Sherbrow/AgYDX/) and [Hash demo (jsfiddle)](http://fiddle.jshell.net/Sherbrow/AgYDX/show/#episodes)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the code. I gave that a try and it still jumps down, even more so than before :)

Comment: @viperfx did you change the html too (IDs) and do you have the page where it is not working ?

Comment: oh you are right, I did not notice that change. Thank you. It is working well now! Just having an issue with this line `var $toggleTab = $('a[href='+hash+']'); ` I append the current url before the hashtag to make sure it stays on same page. so the only issue is the switching of tags on page load when a hash tag exists.

Comment: @viperfx you should keep the hashtag only, because you **do not** need the url in front of it. It can only be source of bugs. Anyway, you can do that : `$toggleTab = $('a[href$="'+hash+'"]');`.

Answer (score 4):

The answer from @Sherbrow didn't work for me. But, The following code did:

```
$('.nav-tabs li a').click( function(e) {
    history.pushState( null, null, $(this).attr('href') );
});
```

Tested on Bootstrap 3.2.0.

I've got this code from [Twitter Bootstrap: How To Prevent Jump When Tabs Are Clicked](http://blog.shaunscovil.com/post/55630727782/twitter-bootstrap-how-to-prevent-jump-when-tabs-are-clic).

Comment: Very effective.. Works for me.. !!

Answer (score 0):

The other way to resolve this is to call 'scrollTop' after the tab is loaded. I do it this way:

```
$("ul.nav-tabs > li > a").on("shown.bs.tab", function (e) {
    var id = $(e.target).attr("href").substr(1);
    window.location.hash = id;
    setTimeout(function () { $("body").scrollTop(0); }, 50);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**2022 Answer**
I found that if you add `preventDefault` and `stopPropagation` then it won't move or jump.

So wherever you add your event listener code...

```js
$(document).on("click", "#icons-tab-2", (event) => {
  event.stopPropagation();

  //insert whatever code you want in here
  //typically I have had to add code to adjust the tab content containers

  event.preventDefault();
});
```

But you should not need to deal with the hashes or the scrollTop as mentioned in other answers.